# Status bar overlaps in Table View controller - is Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, swift2

I am creating an application with a Table view controller. Now my issue is when I try to scroll table rows my title also scrolling. I want to stop scrolling, only for title view. My main.Storyboard looks like this. [image]

And my emulator output looks like this.

[image]

How can i avoid this issue. I want to scroll only row items. In this following structure i want cell only scroll. view must be fixed How can I do it. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you place your title view inside of `tableHeaderView` of tableView. You need to add `UINavigationController` on storyboard and link your `UITableViewController` as a rootViewController.
OR If you want to use custom title view you need to create a `UIViewContoller` and add your views there.

Comment: If I create UIviewcontroller then how can I add tableview and cells. Navigation controller not going to help. Look at my designs title, sub title and some time another label also need to be added

Comment: it's not possible to add any other view outside of table view if you use UITableViewContoller. Adding UITableView to UIViewContoller is more complex. In this case you can't place prototype cells in table view. Here is a good article how to do this http://www.jmeveryday.com/uitableview-inside-uiviewcontroller/

Comment: use UIViewController instead of UITableviewContoller. Instructions are in article

Answer (score 0):

Know that is probably solved but just add your NavigatioCo troller to Storyboard and segue to your UITabkeViewController..UIViewController will appear automaticaly inside the NavigationController without any coding..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If you would like to keep the UITableViewController in the storyboard, without manually placing it into another view, you can embed the UITableViewController in a UINavigationController (Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller) and uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar" in the inspector. This solves the issue with no extra tweaking needed, and it also preserves your UITableViewController's scene in the storyboard.